# Parity installed. How to convert to ethereum classic chain?

Tags: ethereum-classic, parity-wallet

I have recently purchased some ETC (ethereum classic tokens). I wanted to stored them in Parity. I have installed the Parity (Homestead?-same). Then I tried to convert to ETC chain by `CD>parity--chain classic`.

I get the message `"Parity is not recognised as an internal or external commands operable program or batch file"`. What should I do? As I am new I appreciate very much if you can give me a step by step guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Try the following:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity\parity.exe" --chain classic
```

---

**If that doesn't work.**

If the above doesn't work it means that Parity is installed in a none-default location, and we need to find it.

**Step 1:**

Open the Windows Start pannel:

[image]

**Step 2**

Type "Parity" into the search bar.

[image]

**Step 3**

Right click the file named Parity and click "Open file location"

[image]

**Step 4**

The folder in which Parity is installed will appear.

[image]

**Step 5**

Click in the top part of the folder screen where the location of the file is displayed. Then press `Ctrl + C`

[image]

**Step 6**

Open your command line interface (CLI)

[image]

**Step 7**

Right click on your CLI and press "Paste"

[image]

**Step 8**

The location of your parity installation will appear in the CLI

[image]

**Step 9**

Then complete the location by typing `parity.exe --chain classic` after the text you have just pasted into the CLI.

[image]

Comment: Hi Samuel. Thank you for your reply. However, "C:\Program files.....--chain classic" is not or cannot be located in my computer. What should i do next? Was there any problem during my downloading or installing?

Comment: I've updated my answer, to show you how to find the parity installation if it is present on your machine.

Comment: Hi Samuel. I followed your instructions and the location is : C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools OR C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ethcore. Still the same problem appears even with the addition "Parity.....--chain classic". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows it is `parity.exe`, please note the file extension. So try:

`parity.exe --chain classic`

In your command prompt.

Comment: Hi . Thank you for your reply. However, "C:\Program files.....--chain classic" is not or cannot be located in my computer. What should i do next? Was there any problem during my downloading or installing?

Comment: Which path did you install Parity in? The default path is `C:\Program Files\Ethcore\Parity\parity.exe`